# Split a 2D polyline defined through segments and arcs with Python

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I'm looking for a library (preferably in pure Python) or an algorithm able to split, with an arbitrary line, a 2D polyline made of segments and arcs.

The polyline is a sequence of

- segments `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]`
- and arcs `[(cx,cy),radius,start_angle,end_angle)]`, where `end_angle = start_angle + theta` and `theta` is positive if the arc goes counterclockwise and negative otherwise.

Angles are in degrees. The splitting line is actually a segment long enough to split the polyline in two.

I'm looking for an **exact split**, that is arcs can NOT be approximated by segments.

Given a polyline, the splitting function should return two *lists of polylines* (defined as above by segments and arcs), and the polylines in the first list should be the ones laying on the side of origin. I'm talking about *list* of polylines because a sufficiently complex initial polyline could be splitted, on each side, into many separated polylines.

Comment: Are you splitting it based on a mid point or an intersection with another line?

Comment: @LarrytheLlama The splitting line is arbitrary.